# Mysql 1241 operand should contain 1 column s

Tags: python, mysql

I am using scrapy to crawl information and store into mysql.

Some relevant code are:

```
def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
    if item.get('app_name'):           
        tx.execute("""
            insert into af_appinfo (app_name, app_size, app_data_install, app_icon_url, app_download_url, app_desc) 
            values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
            (item['app_name'], item['app_size'], item['app_data_install'], item['icon_url'],item['app_url'], item['app_desc']))
```

The definition of item is:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class WdjcrawlItem(Item):
  icon_url = Field()
  app_url = Field()
  app_name = Field()
  app_desc = Field()
  app_size = Field()
  app_data_install = Field()
```

The crawler works well. BUT  an exception is raised when using mysql. The exception information is :

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 columns)
```

Any mistake about this query?

Comment: Could you show what is the `item` value before the execute happens? Also, please provide the result of `describe af_appinfo`.

Comment: @alecxe I have modified the question.

Comment: I meant what is the *value* of `item` just before the error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you printed the output you get from scapy on the cmdline? Because it 
sounds like you want to put in multi column data when your code/db only expects
a single column. Can you post the output you get from scapy you want to pass into
the Database?

kind regards,

Dirk